# XP MODE: the time on this PC and the current time on the network are different

Tags: time, windows-xp-mode, kerberos

Some folks were monkeying around with the Time service and Kerberos on our Windows 2003 network domain controllers last night, and today I cannot boot up XP Mode on my Windows 7 desktop. I've rebooted Windows 7. When I try to log into our network from XP Mode, I get the error that the (XP Mode's) machine's time and the network's time are different.

How to synchronize XP Mode time with the network?

Answer (score 0):

By 'folks were monkeying around' - any idea what they where trying to achieve? If they've entered a different 'Internet Time Server' which you don't have entered on your desktop then there's very little that you can do to syncronise your time with the servers. They may even have turned off the syncronisation.

XP mode/Windows 7 - regardless which you use it should draw the time & date from your CMOS, at least until windows has loaded/queried the time server.

Comment: Domain members normally synchronize against the DC, not an arbitrary server. On the second thought, since XP Mode continuously syncs against the host machine's clock, if the host is not a member of the same domain, the clocks *may* be different... But still, even if they do use different servers, a couple of milliseconds won't mean anything (Kerberos tolerates up to 5 minutes). "Monkeying around" would mean a significant clock misadjustment on either the DC or the VM host.

Comment: Along the same lines as i was thinking grawity - 'monkeying around' really doesn't imply the same as 'Administration'... ie someone with unauthorised access! :o